# I am a Co-Op offered a full-time job, want to wait for offers from other companies before accepting/denying the offer. How should I respond?

Tags: job-offer, hiring

I am currently finishing up my third co-op rotation at a company and will begin my full-time job search. I am a Chemical Engineering student entering my senior year. The company I am currently working for has told me that they will be offering me a job at the conclusion of my rotation, but I am hesitant to accept the offer until I have a few competing offers to compare it with.

They are going to be making their offer at the end of the summer, and it is too early for me to get a competing offer to compare it to. I wouldn't mind working where I am currently at, by any means. It is a good company and I enjoy the culture, the people, and the work. My only concern is that I am not entirely certain if it will be the best offer that I can receive.

What should I do? I want to be ready to answer their offer when they give it to me and let them know that I intend to take it seriously but that I want to ensure that I am making the best possible decision for myself. I will not accept it immediately without other offers on the table to compare against.

I am near the top of my class and have a lot of good experience, scholarships, etc... for my resume, so I know that I am a very competitive and desirable employee. I got several competing co-op offers from other companies as well, but turned them down in favor of continuing the projects at the company I was currently at. Especially since they had the best competitive pay for co-ops. What to do?

Edit: For clarification this is a company that I currently work at, just in a co-op position not full-time. They will be making the offer in Late August/Early September but I cannot begin to receive competing offers until likely January/February at the earliest as I do not graduate until Spring 2019.

I also have not yet seen the offer, so I do not know how competitive it will be with other standard offers. I just want to be prepared with how to react once the offer is made. Since I work here, it will be offered in person and I don't want to be fumbling for a response when the time comes to give them an answer.

Comment: Hey Luke, welcome to The Workplace :). I suggested that possible duplicate target, as I think is exactly what you are asking, and you will benefit in reading it.

Comment: I will say this:  One in the hand is worth two in the bush.

Comment: I saw that thread and appreciated the assistance it offered, however my situation is a bit different. The main difference is that I am currently working here, and that the job offer will be made well before any other companies begin the interviewing process for new hires in May of next year. They are going to offer at the end of August/early September, and the other companies I am looking at do not begin their hiring process for Spring 2019 graduates until at least January/February at the earliest in some cases. I do not want to decline an offer when I have no other offer to fall back on.

Comment: Does your school have a "careers" department? If so, they might have some stats on graduate entry salaries and benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in a similar situation near my graduation.

It basically comes down to two choices:

- **Play it safe** and take the offer at your current company. After some time, start prepare yourself and look for new opportunities elsewhere, possibly coordinating them so you can have multiple offers at the same time.
- **Risk it**. Decline the offer in hopes you'll find a better one. This will likely prevent you from immediately rejoining your current company if you cannot find a better offer.

There really is no middle option where you can compare offers side-by-side. So it comes down to personal preference over those two options.

And that won't change as you get older. It's very difficult to align interviews and offers so that you can compare them once they've been made.

Make good use of resources such as Glassdoor so that you can choose companies *before you apply*. Yes, it will be *estimates*, but that's really the best you can hope for.

**Personal Advice:**

Go with option 1 (play it safe). This is what I did. I quit my first job after only 4 months (after accepting another offer), and here's what I learned:

- Having a job already increases your appeal to other companies. The point right after graduation is **not** a good time to fish for offers. Companies simply have a good excuse to offer a basic entry-level position. **Option 1 can very likely lead to an early promotion**.
- Job hopping doesn't look very bad for younger employees (to an extent). Take advantage of it.
- Playing it safe might take longer to get your best offer, but it ensures you don't have to worry about having an income or paying the bills.

**Most importantly:** By accepting a full-time position at your current company, you **are not** declining other offers. Other employers will want you *because* you are a full time employee at your current company. It shows them you're valuable. They aren't going to think that you chose your company over them. They are just looking to gain talent to improve their business.

Comment: Wiser words were never spoken